# What is a good mySQL database design for multiple rankings?

Tags: mysql, database-design

I am trying to figure out the best method to design a database that allows users to rank a number of items.

The items are ranked by all users.

Every item will have a rank assigned to it automatically in the beginning. So when I create a user, the rankings table will be auto populated.

So something like this:

```
users (id, name) - 100,000+ entries
items (id, name) - never more than 1,000 entries
```

The only thing I can currently think of to house the rankings is this:

```
rankings (id, user_id, item_id, ranking)
```

But that feels wrong because I'll have 100 million entries in the `rankings` table. I don't know if that's ok? What other option could I use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can each user assign either zero or one ranking to each item? Or can she assign more than one ranking to a given item?

If it's zero-or-one, your ranking table should have these columns

```
 user_id   INT   
 item_id   INT
 ranking   INT
```

The primary key should be the composite key `(user_id, item_id)`. This will disallow multiple rankings for the same item for the same user, and will be decently efficient. Putting a separate id on this table is not the right thing to do.

For the sake of query efficiency I suggest you also create the covering indexes `(user_id, item_id,ranking)` and `(item_id, user_id, ranking)`.

If you can get your hundreds of thousands of users to rank all 1000 items, that will be great. That's a problem any web app developer would love to have.

This table's rows are reasonably small, and with the indexes I mentioned it should perform decently well both at a smaller scale and as you add users.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. The ranking is from 0 to 1 (0.25, 0.33...) and all items will be ranked only once per user. I'll try it out!

Comment: If your rankings are 0 to 1 you should consider using, for your `ranking` column, either a `FLOAT` in the range [0-1] or an `INT` where 0 means 0.0 and 1000 means 1.0.